# Vue Highcharts "TypeError: Cannot read property 'chart' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I am trying to display a chart from Highcharts in Vue.js with Highcharts for Vue. I keep getting the error in the title on the browser console for the watcher I created and the methods (see code below). As well as for other Vue methods (see screenshot below the code).

The watcher triggers the dataSource() method. The dataSource() method is used to read the list and calculate chart data; The const "base" is from where categories and data are going to be extracted. The setup() method is used to set up the chart and display it on the screen (this method will only be triggered when data is ready).

How do I solve these errors ?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
import _ from "lodash";
import { Highcharts } from "highcharts";

export default {
  computed: mapState({
    list: state => state.list
  }),

  //watcher for each time the list is modified. Triggers dataSource() method;
  watch: {
    list() {
      this.dataSource();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    //used to read the list and calculate chart data
    dataSource() {
      const countries = this.list.map(item => item.country);

      //const from where categories and data is going to be extracted
      const base = _(countries)
        .countBy()
        .map((value, key) => ({ key, value }))
        .orderBy(["value"], ["desc"])
        .value();

      const categories = base.map(item => item.key);
      const values = base.map(item => item.value);

      this.setup({ categories, values });
    },

    //used to set up the chart and display on the screen. This method will only be triggered when data is ready
    setup(obj) {
      const { categories, values } = obj;

      Highcharts.chart("container-for-countries", {
        chart: {
          type: "column"
        },
        title: {
          text: "Monthly Average Rainfall"
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: "Source: WorldClimate.com"
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: categories,
          crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: "Rainfall (mm)"
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Quantidade",
            data: values
          }
        ]
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

[image: Screenshot from browser console]

Comment: It seems that you haven't use the official Highcharts-vue wrapper to make it work. Please get to know with this API: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts

From the docs `Load Highcharts as an ES6 module`

`import Highcharts from 'highcharts';`

You are using a named import.

Also, a bit off-topic, but still on topic.. why would you load vue js from CDN, but the other libraries are imported?

Comment: When entering a code snippet here you can choose the framework version you are using (in this scenario Vue). That's what I did and that's why it appears on top of code. It is merely informative.